# gcd of three numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $a, b, n$ be positive integers. Assume that $\gcd(a,b,n)=1$.
It seems that one can prove that there exist two integers
$c$ and $d$ bounded from above by  $( \log n )^{O(1)}$ such that
$   \gcd (ac + bd, n) =1$.  However the only proof I can see is
by a  complicated exclusive-inclusive argument.
I am wondering whether it has been proved somewhere or whether there is
a simpler argument.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Qi

Comment: Is your $O(1)$ an absolute constant (not depending on $a$ and $b$)?

Comment: Yes it is an absolute constant

Comment: You must mean that $|c|$ and $|d|$ can be bounded above? I ask because you emphasize the positivity of $a,b,n$, but notably not these others...

Comment: That is right. $|c|$ and $|d|$ should be bounded above.

Comment: @Qi Just for clarification, were you implying that you already have a proof?

Comment: ...the only reason I am asking is that one of my coauthors and I came across the same problem one time and we ended up settling for something which met our need but was quite a bit weaker than what you are reporting.

Comment: @AH, could you give me the reference to your paper? No I do not have a proof. A heuristic argument indicates the bound can be as small as $(\log n)^{O(1)}$, but I have yet to turn it into a rigorous proof.

Comment: AH: Given $\epsilon>0$, there is (I believe an effectively computable) $N$ such that for all $n > N$, the desired $O(n^\epsilon)$ result holds: see the question answer by The Hamburglar and my comments regarding explicit bounds on Jacobsthal's function.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.12.30

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is yes, there exists $c$ and $d$, even with $c = 1$, and
$d \ll (\log(n))^{O(1)}$. This follows from a result of Iwaniec.

It suffices to assume that $(a,b) = 1$.
Suppose that $(n,b) = e$, which implies that $(a,e) = 1$.

Since $b$ is divisible by $e$, it follow that $(a+bk,e) = 1$
for all integers $k$. Let $m$ denote the largest factor of $n$ such that
$(m,e) = 1$, it clearly satisfies $(m,b) = 1$.

If $(a+bk,m) = 1$, then because $(a+bk,e) = 1$,
one also has $(a+bk,n) = 1$.

Hence the problem becomes: given an integer $m$, and an arithmetic
progression
$$a, a + b, a + 2b, a+3b, a+4b, \ldots $$
with common difference $b$ prime to $m$, can one find a small integer $d$ such
that $a+db$ is prime to $m$?
Equivalently, let $g \in \mathbf{Z}$ be any multiplicative inverse to $b$ mod $m$,
then does there exist a small $d$ such that
$ag + dbg$ is prime to $m$? Equivalently, does there exist a small $d$
such that $ag + d$ is prime to $m$?

Recall the definition of the Jacobsthal function: $j(m)$
is the smallest integer such that any arithmetic progression
of length $j(m)$ (with common difference one) contains an
element which is co-prime to $m$.

If $m|n$, then $j(m) \le j(n)$.
In particular, there exists a $d \le j(m) \le j(n)$ with $c = 1$ such
that $ac+bd$ is prime to $n$.

Finally (the hard part), by a result of Iwaniec (Demonstratio Math. 11 (1978), 225-231 (MR0499895)), if $n$ has
$r$ distinct prime factors, then $j(n) \ll r^2 \log^2 r$, which
implies that
$$j(n) \ll \log^{2}(n) = \log(n)^{O(1)}.$$

Comment: Some minor tweaks: j(n) depends only on the distinct prime divisors of n, so one can replace n in the upper bound by the squarefree part of n.  Further, letting r < log(n) be the number of distinct prime divisors, Iwaniec's result actually implies j(n) << (rlog(r))^2.  Finally, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37679/erik-westzynthiuss-cool-upper-bound-argument-update/56610#56610 and another answer to the same question give alternative explicit bounds on j(n) by Kanold, Stevens, and Paseman with small nonconstant exponent.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Jacobsthal's Function" Paseman, 2011.12.30

Comment: @The Hamburglar: Aha, I wasn't aware of Iwaniec's result- can you give a reference?

Comment: Some comments: 1. The assumption $(a,b)=1$ can be omitted as it is not used in the proof. 2. Iwaniec even proved $j(n)\ll r^2\log^2 r$, where $r$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$, see Demonstratio Math. 11 (1978), 225-231 (MR0499895). As $r\ll\log n/\log\log n$, we have a solution $c,d\ll\log^2 n$ in the OP's question.

Comment: I see Gerhard Paseman made a similiar comment. In fact one can replace $n$ by its squarefree part in the original problem. Also, I believe Iwaniec's estimate is effective, hence the implied constant in $c,d\ll\log^2 n$ can be calculated (in principle).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this earlier but will include it for what it is worth: I don't know  the answer but here are a few observations and conjectures (the one which are *obviously* true are observations and the others are conjectures) along with a reformulation.

Reformulation:

> For each $t \gt 0$ let $n(t)$ be the smallest $n \gt 0$ such that , for some  $a,b$ with $\gcd(a,b,n)=1$, no $ac+bd$ with $\max(|c|,|d|) \le t$ is relatively prime to $n.$ How fast does $n(t)$ grow? Is it bounded by $k^t$ (or $t^k$) for some constant $k$ ?

- We need is to have, for each pair $c,d$ with $\max(|c|,|d|) \le t,$ some prime divisor $p$ of $n$ which divides $ac+bd.$
- A particular prime $p$ can only eliminate *about* $\frac{1}{p}$ of the relevant pairs. It seems likely that $n(t)$ should be the product of the first several primes.
- We may as well assume that $\gcd(a,b)=1$
- For example let us consider $n(2),$ We will need to have none of the expressions $a,b,a+b,a-b,a+2b,a-2b,2a+b,2a-b$ relatively prime to $n.$ Of these $8$ values, at most $3$ are even and at most $3$ are are multiples of $3.$ However, at most $5$ are congruent to $0,2,3$ or $4$ $\mod 6$ There are several ways that this can happen, but in each, it will take 3 different primes to eliminate the remaining expressions. SO $n(2)=2*3*5*7*11=2310.$ One choice that works is $a=7$ and $b=2.$