# Bound the error in estimating a relative totient function

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ be an integer with $k$ prime factors. We know that the number of integers less than $n$ and coprime to it is
 $$\Phi(n)=n-\sum_i\frac n{p_i}+\sum_{i \lt j}\frac n{p_ip_j}-\cdots+(-1)^{k}\frac n{n}=nr$$ where $r=\prod(1-\frac 1{p_i})$.

For any positive integer $x$, the number  of integers less than or equal to $x$ and relatively prime to $n$  is given exactly by the alternating sum $$\Phi(n,x)=x-\sum_i\lfloor{x/{p_i}}\rfloor+\sum_{i \lt j}\lfloor x/{p_ip_j}\rfloor-\cdots+(-1)^{k}\lfloor x/{n}\rfloor$$

> How large and how small can the error $\Phi(n,x)-xr$ be? Can the absolute value of the error exceed $k$?

Certainly the error can be no more (in absolute value) than $2^k$, probably it is easy to show that it could not be more than the middle binomial coefficient $\binom k{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}$. I can see that it could get (almost) as large as $ k $ by imitating the following example:

The integers $1122659, 2245319, 4490639, 8981279, 17962559, 35925119, 71850239$ are a Cunningham chain as is $2,5,11,23,47$ in that each member is prime and one more than twice the previous one. If $n$ is the product of the $7$ primes from the first chain and $x=1122659\cdot64-1=71850175$ then all seven terms $  x/{p_i} $ are just a bit less than an integer so, without the rounding down to an integer, the estimate $rx$ will too small by about $7$ (the other terms are quite small). Of course it is not known for sure that there are arbitrary length chains. Maybe a similar idea could get an error of order $2k$ or $k^2.$

**later** Thanks for the answers. I give one of my own below explaining that actually the best we could hope for is $2^{k-1}$ and then exhibiting a construction of D. H. Lehmer which attains $(1-2/q)2^{k-1}$ for arbitrary $q$. This is pretty much a result of the other answers, but I thought it was worth showing off the construction (which is not immediately clear from the article).

Comment: Just to remind you, this is a generalization of the problem you helped me with last year.  I was looking at the case of primorials then.  It may help in the general case.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Jacobsthal's Function" Paseman, 2012.02.17

Comment: Also, phi(n) is not xr unless x=n.  I like the question, but it needs a little polish.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.17

Comment: Aaron, in your 1st display, each $x$ should be $n$, right?

Comment: Ah yes, the perils of cut and paste. Indeed they should be $n$ and now are.

Comment: A slightly smoother way to phrase this: The running total gives a step function starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(n,\Phi(n)).$ It takes a jump of $1$ at certain integers. The line connecting the endpoints has slope $r$. Does the running total stay between $rx-k$ and $rx+k$? Viewed as path made of vertical and horizontal segments the graph is centrally symmetric.

Comment: Hi...would this question I asked recently help? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88174/a-question-on-an-error-term-arising-from-the-erastothenes-sieve
Taking $n$ as the product of all primes up to $x^{1/2}$ and applying Prime Number Theorem and Merten's theorem gives error asymptotic to constant times $x/\log x$, whereas $k$ is only $\pi(x^{1/2})$. 

Comment: Jacobsthal's function lower bounds tell me that error of k is too much to ask.  Kk^2 might not be.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.17

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all as you remark above, it is easy to see by elementary means that the error is at most $2^k$. It was an old conjecture of Erdos that this error term could be improved to $o(2^k)$. However this conjecture turns out not to be true!

In 1951 Vijayaraghavan proved that the error term $O(2^k)$ is best possible in the sense that for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\delta >0$ you can find an integer $n$ with exactly $k$ distinct prime factors, and a real number $x$, such that

$$\Phi(n,x)-xr>2^{k-1}-\delta.$$

Vijayaraghavan's paper is *On a problem in elementary number theory. J. Indian Math. Soc. 15, (1951)*.

For a more detailed and up to date discussion you could look at the more recent paper  *Codecà, Nair, An extension of a result of Lehmer on numbers coprime to n. Ramanujan J. 16 (2008), no. 1, 59–71.*

Comment: Do you recall what could be said about such x that gave such a large error, or how many intervals of such x existed for small delta?  (I imagine there would be at least k! many.) Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.18

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman No, I'm not sure but that sounds like an interesting question.

Comment: At least for the simpler proof of Lehmer the example is pretty explicit. For $n=29\cdot 59 \cdot 89 \cdot 149$ (made of primes of the form $30c-1$ )  it is $x=\frac{n+29}{30}-1.$ I tried to spell this out a bit in an answer below.

Answer (score 6):

In fact the absolute value could not be greater than $2^{k-1}.$ Let $\{z\}=z-\lfloor z \rfloor$ denote the fractional part of $z$, then $$\Phi(n,x)-xr=0-\sum_i\{x/{p_i}\}+\sum_{i \lt j}\{ x/{p_ip_j}\}-\cdots+(-1)^{k}\{x/{n}\}$$ is a sum of $2^k$ terms, each between $0$ and $1$, half added and half subtracted. There is no reason to expect the first $k$ primes to give the optimal gap, and in fact they do not. For that matter, the question would be as interesting to me if the $p_i$ are simply relatively prime integers. The references given by Alan Haynes are apt and lead one to look at the article [The distribution of totatives](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1955-038-5)  by D. H. Lehmer. Even there the key example is a bit hard to work out. If $q$ is any integer and $p_1\lt\dots\lt p_k$ are $k$ primes all of the form $p_i=c_iq-1$ then for $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ there is a number $1 \lt x \lt n$ for which $|\Phi(n,x)-xr| \gt 2^{k-1} \frac{q-2}{q}.$  Let $C=\prod c_i$ It is esy to see that $$n=Cq^k-(\sum_iC/c_i)q^{k-1}+(\sum_{i\lt j}C/c_ic_j)q^{k-2}-\cdots+(-1)^k.$$  A similar expression holds for any product of several of the $p_i.$ The essentially unique extremal $x$ is $$\frac{n +(-1)^kp_1}{q}-1.$$ At this point I will simply illustrate with $k=4.$ Then

$$n=c_{1}c_{2}c_{3}c_{4}{q}^{4}- \left( c_{1}c_{2}c_{3}+c_{1}c_{2}c_{4}+c_{1}c_{3}c_{4}+c_{2}c_{3}c_{4} \right) {q}^{3} $$$$ + \left( c_{1}c_{2}+c_{1}c_{3}+c_{1}c_{4}+c_{2}c_{3}+c_{2}c_{4}+c_{3}c_{4} \right) {q}^{2}- \left( c_{1}+c_{2}+c_{3}+c_{4} \right) q+1$$

and $$x=c_{1}c_{2}c_{3}c_{4}{q}^{3}- \left( c_{1}c_{2}c_{3}+c_{1}c_{2}c_{4}+c_{1}c_{3}c_{4}+c_{2}c_{3}c_{4} \right) {q}^{2} $$$$ + \left( c_{1}c_{2}+c_{1}c_{3}+c_{1}c_{4}+c_{2}c_{3}+c_{2}c_{4}+c_{3}c_{4} \right) {q}- \left( c_{2}+c_{3}+c_{4} \right)-1 $$  So $$x/p_1p_2p_3p_4-\lfloor x/p_1p_2p_3p_4\rfloor =x/n \approx 1/q$$ while, each term $$x/p_i-\lfloor x/p_i\rfloor=1-\frac{c_i-c_1+1}{c_iq-1} \approx 1-1/q $$ and each term $$x/(p_ip_j)-\lfloor x/(p_ip_j)\rfloor=\frac{c_ic_jq-(c_i+c_j)+c_1-1}{c_ic_jq^2-(c_i+c_j)q+1}\approx 1/q.$$ The terms of one sign are very about $1/q$ and those of the other are about $1-1/q.$ this accounts for the entire summation being close to $(1-2/q)2^{k-1}$

The other extreme is at $n-1-x$.

Answer (score 1):

Westzynthius showed that for large k, and n the kth primorial, there were gaps of length greater than p_k g(p_k), where g was some increasing function involving log(p_k) and iterated log of p_k, the kth prime. This implies that there will be horizontal segments of at least that length in the graph Aaron Meyerowitz suggests.  I'll do the arithmetic later, but I expect it to lead to an error of something like k log(k) minimum.  Using Jacobsthal's function and Iwaniec's estimate, it is likely that the error is bounded by k^2.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.17

Comment: Note that one could have a very long horizontal segment and yet stay very close to a sloped line provided that the slope is small.