# Should I expect to see numbers this smooth?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a sequence $N_k$ of numbers whose growth I wish to determine, or at least
approximate nicely. When I look at the ratios of consecutive members, 
I find some interesting simplifications occurring.  Part of this can 
be explained by how I generate these numbers, but I am still 
surprised at how smooth these numbers are. Is there a good explanation for this?
Also, any references which might point to material related to this sequence,
 or talks about the growth of the $N_k$ or fractions $N_k/P_k$,
would be appreciated.

Given $n$ I am trying to figure out how "bad" a linear approximation is to the
number of totients of n in an interval.  MathOverflow 88877
[Bound the error in estimating a relative totient function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88777/) 
covers some general
theory, but I am focussing on the case n is the $k$th primorial $P_k$.
I generate differences between consecutive totients, and use that
to compare the actual number of totients in $(0,x]$ with the predicted 
number $x\phi(P_k)/P_k$.
I actually am computing the numerator $N_k$ of a fraction: $N_k/P_k$ will 
turn out to be the maximum difference over all $x \in (0,P_k)$
 between the actual count in $(0, x] to the expected value .

I compute this in a loop by adding multiples of $\phi(P_k)$ and subtracting $P_k$
in each iteration, so I expect all values, including the maximum, to be multiples
of $\gcd(P_k,\phi(P_k))$.  Even after factoring that out, I still find the result
to be smooth.  I now list $N_k$ and the "leftover factors" that result after
removing those common to $P_k$ and $\phi(P_k)$:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
 k & N_k & \textrm{leftover factors} \\
1  & 1   & 1   \\
2  & 4   & 2    \\
3  & 28   & 2,7  \\
4  & 318   & 53   \\
5  & 5820  & 2,97  \\
6  & 106530 & 53,67 \\
7  & 2776560 & 2,2,2,23,503 \\
8  & 83991240 & 2,2,3,181,1289 \\
9  & 3216557520 & 2,2,2,3,11,31,397 \\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

$N_k$ is $a*\phi(P_k)- b * P_k$ for some $a \lt P_k$ and $b \lt \phi(P_k)$, and one
expects $b/a$ often to be near $\phi(P_k)/P_k$.
However, I am still surprised by the smoothness of $N_k$ for $k \gt 5$.
(The appearance of $53$ twice also interests me.) Is this to be
expected, perhaps as a consequence of Guy's Strong law of Small Numbers?

Gerhard "Large Numbers Made From Small" Paseman, 2014.01.29