# Greatest number of coprime numbers between two numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

We know that from prime number theorem that the number of primes below $n$ is approximately $$\frac{n}{\log_en}.$$

**$\star$** Given $n,m$, what is the largest list of pairwise coprime numbers that one can come up above $n$ and below $m$? Will it be asymptotically same as number of primes or something different? In particular can we replace $\log_en$ by something smaller? If so, how much smaller?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56099/lower-bound-of-the-number-of-relatively-primeseach-other-in-an-interval

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a given $n$, let $P\subset\{2,3\dots,n\}$ be the set of primes up to $n$, and let $S\subset\{2,3\dots,n\}$ be any subset with pairwise coprime elements. Consider the function $f:S\to P$ that assigns to any $s\in S$ its smallest prime factor $p\in P$. It is clear that $f$ is an injection, whence $|S|\leq|P|$.

In short, the set of primes up to $n$ is the largest subset of $\{2,3,\dots,n\}$ with the given property.

**Added 1.** Péter Komjáth kindly called my attention to a [1962 survey by Paul Erdős](http://renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1962-23.pdf) (in Hungarian), which discusses some related problems. In particular, Problem 4 can be solved by the argument above: if $1\leq a_1<\dots<a_k\leq n$ are such that no $a_i$ divides the product of the other $a_j$'s, then $k\leq\pi(n)$. Problems 10 and 11 are based on a [1938 paper of Erdős](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1938-07-Jav.pdf) and some later developments. Most relevant is Problem 18 that discusses the OP's question in general intervals. He denotes by $F(n,k)$ the maximal size of a subset  $S\subset\{n+1,\dots,n+k\}$ with pairwise coprime elements, and he mentions that estimating this quantity is a difficult problem. In particular, he says that he is far from solving completely the problem of determining or estimating $\max_n F(n,k)$. I am sure that digesting the vast [Erdős archive](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/Erdos.html) would bring up many related questions and results, in particular estimates for $F(n,k)$.

**Added 2.** The problem of estimating $F(n,k)$ (see previous section) is discussed in more detail in this [1971 paper of Erdős](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1971-03.pdf). See also the relevant [OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A062575).

Comment: oops I meant an interval. I was looking at joro's post and forgot to update.

Comment: Using PNT we can count number of primes between $m$ and $n$. Do we have roughly the same statistics for number of pairwise coprime numbers between $m$ and $n$ (this was what was in my mind)?

Comment: I think from your answer it should be same.

Comment: @Arul: For general intervals the size of such a subset might exceed the number of primes in the interval, e.g. $\{5,6,7\}$ vs. $\{5,7\}$, but probably by not too much. One can certainly estimate the size with the usual sieves, but I don't know the state of the art here. Something tells me Erdős worked on this problem, but I don't have time to think about this or check the literature. The general question is definitely more interesting.

Comment: I am thinking following: Number of coprimes integers in $[n,m]$ = number between $[0,m]$ - number between $[0,n]$. Each term in difference follows PNT from your post?

Comment: @Arul: I guess by "number of coprimes integers in $[n,m]$" you mean "maximal size of a subset $S\subset[n,m]$ consisting of pairwise coprime integers". I don't think there will be a precise equation as you envision, but as I said all three terms will be very close to the actual prime count in the three given intervals, so the equation will hold up to a little error. Estimating the error precisely is a subtle problem in my opinion, and probably Erdős worked on this problem.

Comment: @GH from MO: http://renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1962-23.pdf

Comment: @Péter Komjáth Does the paper exist in English?

Comment: @PéterKomjáth I cannot read hungarian, would it be possible to summarize results and asymptotics in a few sentences?

Comment: @PéterKomjáth: I added a brief summary of some relevant parts of the Erdős survey, thanks a lot for sharing it!

Comment: @Arul: See my added sections.