# A question concerning products of finite cyclic groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, co.combinatorics, open-problems

Let $m_1,\ldots, m_n$ be pairwise coprime natural numbers $\geq 1$. We consider the product $$G(m_1,\ldots,m_n) := \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{Z} / m_i \mathbb{Z}.$$ We define $M(n)$ as the set $n$-tuple of natural numbers $\geq 1$ with the property that the entrys are pairwise coprime. We define $l : M(n) \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$ by $$l(m_1,\ldots,m_n) = \max_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in G(m_1,\ldots,m_n)} \min \{ k \in \mathbb{N}_0 | x_i+k \neq 0 \forall 1 \leq i \leq n \},$$
hence $l(m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ may be regarded as the maximal distance of the elements of $G$ from the elements which have no identity in their entrys. It is clear, that $l(m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ is always a natural number.

The question is now: Does there exist a real number $r$, such that $$r \cdot n \cdot \ln (n) \geq \sup_{(m_1,\ldots,m_n) \in M(n)} l(m_1,\ldots,m_n)$$ holds for all $n >> 0$ and is it possible to take $r=2$ ?

Comment: Could you please clarify the definition of $l(m_i,...)$, there seems to be a typo.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Hopefully, the typos is clear now.

Comment: I am afraid not. What is the role of k in the max min?

Comment: What do you mean by the role of k ? It should be an absolute constant.

Comment: In the displayed formula where a max min appears you say k in N_0 but this k appears nowhere; except later a different(?) k appears.

Comment: What are you taking the  minimum of?
It seems it is the minimum of all $k$ such that... and the condition that follows does not contain $k$. Do you want $k$ instead of $n$?

Comment: No, x_i + k should be not zero for all i as the condition of l(m_1,...,m_n)


Comment: I would think the supremum is attained on the sequence of consecutive primes. Is it? And if so, can you construct a point $(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1})$ that will reach $l(p_1,\dots,p_n,p_{n+1})$ by taking $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ that does it for $l(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ and adjoining the only possible integer $x_{n+1}=-l(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ to it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. I checked it for the first 10-15 cases and there were counterexamples.

Comment: counterexamples to what part? The construction of a good sequence?

Comment: Exactly, I also hoped, that I could construct a sequence like you wanted, but that is unfortunately not possible...

Comment: Gjergji's answer does not need confirmation.  I confirm it anyway, and link to a related answer (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37679/erik-westzynthiuss-cool-upper-bound-argument-update/56610#56610) which contains a link to a paper of Hagedorn on Jacobsthal's function.  The answer contains an attempt of mine to improve an explicit upper bound by Stevens;  I have since improved that improvement, but have not found Erdos' exponent yet.  Westzynthius's paper from 1931 will show that your desired r does not exist.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.04.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $l(m_1,\cdots,m_n)$ is <s>at least</s> equal to the maximum length of a sequence of consecutive integers each of which is divisible by some $m_i$. Let's suppose for a moment that $m_i$ is the $i$th prime. In "On the problem of Jacobsthal", Iwaniec proves that this number is $\ll (n\log n)^2$, while your bound would be much stronger, and if you see the lower bound I mention in [this equvalent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17526/smallest-integer-not-divisible-by-integers-in-a-finite-set) ($\sim\frac{n(\log n)^2 \log \log \log n}{(\log \log n)^2}$), it is actually false. In any case the question reduces to finding the best upper bound on [Jacobsthal's function](http://oeis.org/A058989) (In the comments of the question I linked to above there is an argument for why it suffices to reduce to the $m_i$ prime case).

Comment: Thank you very much Gjergji. But naturally the most important example of this is, as you already said, when $m_i$ is the i-th prime. If we would regard $l(m_1,...,m_n)$ for this case, could we give a good bound for $l(m_1,...,m_n)$ ?

Comment: When $m_i$ are prime then $l(m_i)$ is equal to Jacobsthal's function. Except for Iwaniec's bound I mentioned here, and Erdos' bound in the other question, I am not aware of further improvement on lower or upper bounds.

Comment: I never heard of the Jacobsthal function before. Thas helps me quite a lot. Thank you, Gjergji.